# Javascript - merging single Object properties

Tags: javascript, object

Let's suppose I have a Javascript Object like this:

```
var obj = {
    prop1: {
        subProp: [ 1 ]
    },
    prop2: {
        subProp2: [ 2 ]
    },
    prop3: {
        subProp: [ 3 ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a multidimentional Object with some subpropeties that are equal. What I wanted is to merge this subproperties and collect them into a new object, like this:

```
var obj2 = {
    subProp: [ 1, 3 ],
    subProp2: [ 2 ]
}
```

Which is the best way to do this? I don't mind using plain Javascript or jQuery to do that.

Thanks for any tip or advice!

Comment: Would the properties always be an array of numbers that you are attempting to merge together?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney yes! The subproperties needs to be merged together (I.E. if I have 10 subproperties named as `subProp`, the new object should have only one `subProp`, with all the values merged. In this case, the values would be always an array of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a very specific case, it'd almost certainly be better try and develop a general solution to the problem. However, this code does what you are looking for.

```
function mergeSubProps(host, allowDuplicates) {
  var merged = {};

  // iterate over the keys of the outer object      
  Object.keys(host).forEach(function(outerKey) {
    var property = host[outerKey];

    // iterate over the keys of the inner object
    Object.keys(property).forEach(function(key) {

      // get the values of this key (assuming array)
      var values = property[key];
      merged[key] = merged[key] || [];

      if(!allowDuplicates) {
        // remove duplicates from the values array
        values = values.filter(function(value) {
          return merged[key].indexOf(value) < 0;
        });
      }

      // add these values to the object we're merging into
      merged[key] = merged[key].concat(values);
    });
  });

  return merged;
}
```

---

**Edit**: Added a second argument that will allow/disallow duplicate values in the final merged array. If you omit the second argument, it will default to false and duplicates will be excluded.

Comment: Awesome! This very elegant, readable and is almost perfect. One little question: is it possible to merge the array of numbers from the subproperties? This way we don't have anything like `subprop: [1,3,1,2]`, only `subprop: [1,3,2]`.

Comment: @DiegodeOliveira Is "merge the array of numbers from the subproperties" the same as make sure there are no duplicate entries? Not sure I fully understand?

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks! This is just what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most performant code, but something like this...

```
// Merge subProp arrays
for (var prop in obj) {
    for (var subProp in obj[prop]) {
        obj2[subProp] = obj[prop][subProp].concat(obj2[subProp] || []);
    }
}

// Remove duplicates
for (var subProp in obj2) {
    obj2[subProp] = obj2[subProp].filter(function (item, pos) {
        return obj2[subProp].indexOf(item) == pos}
    );
}
```

It'd be a lot less code if using LoDash or Underscore.